# Changing the text on the Django Form wizard submit button

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

How can I change the text on the Django Form Wizard submit button?

```
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}" class="btn btn-inverse">First step</button>
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}" class="btn btn-inverse">Previous Step</button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Basically what I want to do is instead of "Submit" being the value of the "Next" button I would like it to say "Next" until the last step then it should say "Submit". I read about creating a custom template for each step but that would seem like extreme overkill to do for a simple text change on the button, is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a way to see if you're currently in the last step of the wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}" class="btn btn-inverse">First step</button>
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}" class="btn btn-inverse">Previous Step</button>
{% endif %}

{% if wizard.steps.current == wizard.steps.last %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
{% else %}
<input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary" />
{% endif %}
```

That should be the overall idea. Take a look at the [wizard doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/).

Hope this helps!